# Graph Theory find best configuration

Tags: python, graph

Imagine I have the following graph

```
A . . . B . . . C  . . . EXIT

. . . . . . . . . . . . . . 

. . . . . . . . . . . . . .

D . . . E . . . F . . . . G
```

I have 7 "rooms" (A-B...) and 7 groups of let's say ants. First group of ants has 7 ants, the second has 6 ants, the third 5 ants and so on.
I must attribute to each room a group so that the distance traveled by the whole groups is the minimum.

I have figured to use list permutations in order to check for all the combinations, calculate the distance and compare. See below. This bruteforce works in this case with !8 permutations but in my actual project I have up to 42 rooms, I'm not able to calculate !42 combinations.

Any ideas ?

```
import pandas as pd
import math
import numpy as np
import itertools

def calculateDistance(df, porte_a, porte_b):
    try:
        coord_a = [(x, df.columns[y]) for x, y in zip(*np.where(df.values == porte_a))][0]
        coord_b = [(x, df.columns[y]) for x, y in zip(*np.where(df.values == porte_b))][0]
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print("Couldn't find the coordinates")
        return
    y1, x1 = coord_a[0], coord_a[1]
    y2, x2 = coord_b[0], coord_b[1]
    dist = math.sqrt(((x2 - x1) **2)  + ( (y2 - y1) **2 ))
    return dist

gates = [x for x in range(1, 8)]
combinations = list(itertools.permutations(gates))

overall_distances = {}
paths = {6:3,
        1: 8,
        2: 7,
         3: 6,
         4:5,
         5: 4,
         7:2,
         8:-1
        }

def calculate_path(df, i):
    print(i)
    distance = calculateDistance(df, i, "exit")    
    for j in range(paths[i]):
        distance += calculateDistance(df, i, "exit")
    return distance

def calculate_distance(df, list_points):
    distance = 0
    for i in list_points:
        distance += calculate_path(df, i)
    return distance

for i in combinations:
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    df[0] = [i[0], 0, 0, 0, 0, i[1]]
    df[1] = [i[2], 0, 0, 0, 0, i[3]]
    df[2] = [i[4], 0, 0, 0, 0, i[5]]
    df[3] = [i[6], 0, 0, 0, 0, "exit"]
    overall_distances[i] = calculate_distance(df, i)

print(min(overall_distances.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]))
print(max(overall_distances.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]))
```

Comment: Have you looked at [networkx](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/index.html)? It's the canonical library to work with graphs...

Comment: Also – there's absolutely no need to use Pandas here, it won't help you at all.

Comment: Yes I know I don't need to use panda, fact is I will receive the graph as an excel file so that's why I used it. But I guess I could transform the dataframe into a two dimensional array you're right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Sort the rooms into order of increasing distance
- Assign the largest group to the closest room
- Assign 2nd largest group to second closest room
- ...

Optimization: Since you do not care about the absolute distances, just the relative distances of the rooms, you can compare the squares of their distance, saving 42 square root calculations.